# method added via refinement not visible in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refinements

I have refined the `Enumerable` module in a Rails controller as follows, adding one method that, as far as I know, doesn't already exist in Rails or the standard library:

```
module OrderedGroupBy
  refine Enumerable do
    def ordered_group_by(&block)
      items = each
      groups = []
      prev = nil
      loop do
        begin
          i = items.next
          current = i.instance_eval(&block)
          groups << [] if current != prev
          prev = current
          groups.last << i
        rescue StopIteration
          break
        end
      end
      groups
    end
  end
end

using OrderedGroupBy

class TestController < ApplicationController
  def test
    numbers = ['one', 'three', 'seven', 'four', 'nine']
    @groups = numbers.ordered_group_by(&:length)
  end
end
```

Calling the controller action `test` results in a `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `ordered_group_by' for ["one", "three", "seven", "four", "nine"]:Array
```

To narrow down the problem, I created a standalone file with the same structure (without the Rails environment):

```
module OrderedGroupBy
  refine Enumerable do
    def ordered_group_by(&block)
      items = each
      groups = []
      prev = nil
      loop do
        begin
          i = items.next
          current = i.instance_eval(&block)
          groups << [] if current != prev
          prev = current
          groups.last << i
        rescue StopIteration
          break
        end
      end
      groups
    end
  end
end

using OrderedGroupBy

class TestController < Object
  def test
    numbers = ['one', 'three', 'seven', 'four', 'nine']
    @groups = numbers.ordered_group_by(&:length)
  end
end

TestController.new.test
```

In this case, calling the test method has the expected result:

```
# => [["one"], ["three", "seven"], ["four", "nine"]]
```

Also, if I define the ordered_group_by method directly on Enumerable, without using `refine`, I can successfully call the method.

Is there some reason why this would not work as a refinement in the context of Rails, or is there something else I'm missing?

Edit: I'm using rails 5.2.0, and this is an empty project, with only `rails new _` and `rails generate controller Test test` having been run.

Comment: Would not putting `using OrderedGroupBy` _inside_ class definition help?

Comment: @mudasobwa Tried that, same result

Comment: You don't need `begin`, `end`, `rescue StopIteration` and `break`. [Kernel#loop](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) handles the `StopIteration` exception by breaking out of the loop. Also, `class C; end; C.superclass #=> Object`, so why `class TestController < Object` rather than just `class TestController`?

Comment: Not an answer, but FYI: `numbers.slice_when { |a, b| a.size != b.size }.to_a`

Comment: @Cary Swoveland you're right, I'm sorry. I'm deleting my comment so as not to confuse anybody

Comment: Did you try refining `Array` instead of `Enumerable` ?

Comment: @gasc that worked, but what I don't understand is why the behavior is different under Rails